# Selenium Does Click on Firefox but PhantomJS doesn't (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, click, phantomjs

i'm really new to Selenium WebDriver. I write a simple code for out of curiousity. I made an spam bot to open a page, shuffle in online users list and click everyone of them in order. Send some message, close the new window and repeat.

I made this work on Selenium Firefox driver. It seems work good. But i want to do it silent, not opening firefox everytime. So i found out i can do that by PhantomJS.

Here is my working code for firefox:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

def setup
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  @reklam = 'Some testing message.'
end

def run
  setup

  @driver.get 'http://c2.me/okanb3'
  first_window = @driver.window_handle

  begin
    @driver.switch_to.window(first_window)

    @driver.find_element(link_text: "Shuffle").click
    sleep 20
    elements = @driver.find_elements(:class, 'shufflelink')

    elements.each do |x|

      x.click
      all_windows = @driver.window_handles
      new_window = all_windows.select { |this_window| this_window != first_window }

      @driver.switch_to.window(new_window)

      if @driver.page_source.include? 'The user is not available right now.' or @driver.page_source.include? 'User account is disabled.'
        @driver.close
        @driver.switch_to.window(first_window)
      else
        input = @driver.find_element(:id, 'inputbox')

        input.send_keys(@reklam)
        input.send_keys:return

        @driver.close
        popup = @driver.switch_to.alert
        popup.accept
        @driver.switch_to.window(first_window)
      end
    end
  end while TRUE
end

run
```

But when i switch Webdriver from Firefox to PhantomJS, x.click method doesn't work. I made some tests and program doesnt go further from click method. After a while program ends with (Net::ReadTimeout) error.

Here is my last try to work it proper;

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

def setup
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs
  @reklam = 'http://peyloride.com siteme beklerim.'
end

def teardown
  @driver.quit
end

def run
  setup
  @driver.manage.window.resize_to(1920, 1080)
  @driver.get 'http://c2.me/okanb3'
  first_window = @driver.window_handle

  begin
    @driver.switch_to.window(first_window)

    @driver.find_element(link_text: "Shuffle").click
    puts "Shuffleandı"
    sleep 20
    elements = @driver.find_elements(:class, 'shufflelink')

    elements.each do |x|

      puts "click'e geldik"
      @driver.save_screenshot "phantomjs.png"
      x.click
      @driver.save_screenshot "phantomjs2.png"
      puts "click yaptı sonunda aq"
      all_windows = @driver.window_handles
      new_window = all_windows.select { |this_window| this_window != first_window }

      @driver.switch_to.window(new_window)

      if @driver.page_source.include? 'The user is not available right now.' or @driver.page_source.include? 'User account is disabled.'
        @driver.close
        @driver.switch_to.window(first_window)
      else
        input = @driver.find_element(:id, 'inputbox')

        input.send_keys(@reklam)
        input.send_keys:return

        @driver.close
        popup = @driver.switch_to.alert
        popup.accept
        @driver.switch_to.window(first_window)
      end
    end
  end while TRUE
end

run
```

As you can see i tried to take a screenshot to understand the problem but screenshot seems really fine. Here it is:

[image]

EDIT: Versions:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]

gem list
...
selenium-webdriver (2.48.1)
...

phantomjs -v
1.9.0
```

Comment: Maybe you should try setting an implicit wait `@driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10 # seconds`. Check [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits).

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.  @JasonEstibeiro

Comment: Can you provide versions please?

Comment: Thanks in advance just added at end of the op. @comjf